# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pipenv==2018.10.13' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I've reinstalled pip and pipenv due to some broken package with ansible. Now, it seems like my pip dependencies are all screwed. Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.

```
$ which python2
 /usr/local/bin/python2

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ which pipenv
/usr/local/bin/pipenv


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/bin/pipenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3123, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3107, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3136, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 580, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 593, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pipenv==2018.10.13' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Fixed: find which directory pipenv is install at. rm -rf /your/pipenv/path/. then do pip uninstall -force pipenv. Then reinstall with brew install pipenv should fix the issue. Cheers

Comment: Fixed with `brew uninstall pipenv` and `brew install pipenv`.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had the same problem. You should reinstall `pipenv` using the same package manager you used the first time.

- If the installation was done using `pip`, then:

  ```
  pip uninstall pipenv
  pip install pipenv
  ```
- If you are using `brew`, then you must run the commands [exposed by Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1489151/andrei)

  ```
  brew uninstall pipenv
  brew install pipenv
  ```

To check if `pipenv` installation was successfully completed, run:
`pipenv --version`

#### From the comments, alternatively use:

```
brew reinstall pipenv
```

Comment: Or just `brew reinstall pipenv`

Comment: What's actually happening in this situation? I have the brew version and I've had this happen to me twice now.

Comment: @wojonatior I would be interested to know this as well

Comment: @Connor@wojonatior, I believe this had to do with pip and brew libraries are conflicted as to which one to use, that's why I always have each project for each virtualenv

Answer (score 5):

This should fix the problem too:

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv check
pipenv sync
```

I run into this problem from time to time when updating python using anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

if you get this kind of "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'filelock<4,>=3.4.1' distribution was not found and is required by virtualenv" error you can also solve it by
navigating to the folder and then run "pip install pipenv"

Answer (score 0):

first go to the virtual env directory by typing below command on the terminal

```
cd ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/
```

then check for a directory having project name as prefix, and open terminal inside that directory and type

```
mkdir bin; cp local/bin/python bin/
```

after this go the the your project directory and run `pipenv install` again.