# Python DistributionNotFound issue

Tags: python, anaconda

I’m undergoing a strange issue, so wanted to see if anyone can advise what’s going on here please.

So the below worked absolutely fine in the morning and now when I run the same code (without any changes) I get following error "**DistributionNotFound: The 'packaging' distribution was not found and is required by the application**” , which makes me feel there is something seriously wrong with our environment or perhaps its me

Any idea what is this DistributionNotFound ? I hope there is more clear error logging, that will help me debug this. Again nothing changed to the code that worked wonderful in the morning.

Below is my code. Also, tail -f ../preparing shows all packages are successfully installed as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

test_query = """
SELECT * from TBL
"""
conn = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://testredshitserver:1234/testdb',connect_args={'sslmode': 'prefer'})
df = pd.read_sql_query(test_query,conn)
display (df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pkg\_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pipenv==2018.10.13' distribution was not found and is required by the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729909/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-the-pipenv-2018-10-13-distribution-was-no)

Comment: Do you have an additional python installation available on your computer? Or did you run your code inside a virtual environment? Did you use Anaconda in the morning and NO-Anaconda later?

Comment: @squeezer44 Thank u for swift response.. Sadly that isnt applicable.. i'm using Anaconda distribution and also tried those link suggested pipenv commands as well.. no luck.. I only have one environment.. nothing changed. I use Anaconda Enterprise server in cloud

Comment: @stack user: Did you run your code inside a virtual environment?

Comment: @squeezer44 inside my container.. I have anaconda enterprise installed on docker

Comment: It seems to be somehow related with the anaconda docker container. So I recommend either to test the code under pure Python locally or in the Cloud (e.g.: with Google Colab). That's to get a better idea what could went wrong with your docker container.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I found the root cause, but not idea why we have such a behavior.

So to make this work I need to manually “pip install sqlalchemy-redshift”, but as you can see below it says the requirement is already satisfied. Since I did specify this package in my .yml. Why is this working only after again issuing a pip install sqlalchemy-redshift??

How do I get this working via auto install from .yml?

[image]